# Rollback trans and unlock tables on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Hy , sometimes I had problems with `SQL Server` because of unknown transactions left opened or a lock table, and I read many suggestion to avoid restarting the server
until I found this , and it seems to work
do you have others suggestion to release locks and rollback trans ?
because I am reserved on running this on a production server

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE [db_dev]
SET SINGLE_USER
WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
ALTER DATABASE [db_dev]
SET MULTI_USER;
GO
```

Comment: Have you identified *what* is holding the locks? You can `KILL` an individual connection without restarting the server or taking the database offline.

Comment: You can use KILL for locks and (have developers) query the value of @@TRANCOUNT for open transactions. You could also maybe use   SET XACT_ABORT ON for some procs, statements

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check what is blocking your process by using

```
sp_who2
```

then

```
kill spid
```

setting it to single_user then reverting back will drop all connections to that database. Can be very dangerous on production servers.

Answer (score 2):

If you have lock on a table you can kill that with below code :

```
    SELECT OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) AS TableName,
           Resource_type,
           request_session_id
    FROM sys.dm_tran_locks AS L
         JOIN sys.partitions AS P ON L.resource_associated_entity_id = p.hobt_id
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(P.object_id) = '<Table_Name>';

    GO
    Kill session_ID
```

Comment: This doesn't work when sys.dm_tran_locks is also locked.